# Generar copia de un registro cargado en un modal

Tags: php, modal

Estoy intentado que un modal que carga los datos (sin script), una vez los datos cargados en el formulario quiero que esos datos generen un duplicado, supongo que seria como generar una nuevo registro pero no me devuelve ningún error ni me realiza nada en concreto. Paso código del modal y del controlador:
```  
">



" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">



 Copiar / Duplicar Tarea

×

````
                                                <form action="../../app/controllers/actividad/duplicar_tarea.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label for="">Proyecto: <?php echo $nombre_py ?></label>
                                                                <input type="text" value="<?php echo $id_proyecto ?>" name="id_proyecto" class="form-control" hidden>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>


                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-md-7">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label for="">Tarea</label>
                                                                <input type="text" value="<?php echo $nombre_ta ?>" name="nombre_ta" class="form-control" required>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                                            <label for="">Centro Trabajo</label>
                                                            <select name="centro_ta" id="" class="form-control">
                                                                <?php
                                                                foreach ($centros_datos as $centro_dato) {
                                                                    $centro_tabla = $centro_dato['nombre_cen'];
                                                                    $id_centro = $centro_dato['id_centro']; ?>
                                                                    <option value="<?php echo $id_centro; ?>" <?php if ($centro_tabla == $centro_ta) { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>>
                                                                        <?php echo  $centro_tabla; ?>
                                                                    </option>
                                                                <?php
                                                                }
                                                                ?>
                                                            </select>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-2">
                                                            <label for="">Responsable</label>
                                                            <select name="responsable_ta" id="" class="form-control">
                                                                <?php
                                                                foreach ($responsables_datos as $responsable_dato) {
                                                                    $responsable_tabla = $responsable_dato['nombre_resp'];
                                                                    $id_responsable = $responsable_dato['id_responsable']; ?>
                                                                    <option value="<?php echo $id_responsable; ?>" <?php if ($responsable_tabla == $responsable_ta) { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>>
                                                                        <?php echo  $responsable_tabla; ?>
                                                                    </option>
                                                                <?php
                                                                }
                                                                ?>
                                                            </select>
                                                        </div>

                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-md-1">
                                                            <label for="">Programada</label>
                                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="programada_ta" id="flexRadioDefault1" value="1">
                                                                <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
                                                                    SI
                                                                </label>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="programada_ta" id="flexRadioDefault2" value="0" checked>
                                                                <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault2">
                                                                    NO
                                                                </label>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-2">
                                                            <label for="">Prioridad</label>
                                                            <select class="form-select form-select-sm" name="prioridad_ta" aria-label=".form-select-sm example">
                                                                <option value="<?php echo $prioridad_ta ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $prioridad_ta ?></option>
                                                                <option>Seleccione</option>
                                                                <option value="Baja">BAJA</option>
                                                                <option value="Media">MEDIA</option>
                                                                <option value="Alta">ALTA</option>
                                                            </select>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-2">
                                                            <label for="">Categoria</label>
                                                            <select class="form-select form-select-sm" name="categoria_ta" aria-label=".form-select-sm example">
                                                                <option value="<?php echo $categoria_ta ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $categoria_ta ?></option>
                                                                <option>Seleccione</option>
                                                                <option value="Documentos">Documentos</option>
                                                                <option value="Formación">Formación</option>
                                                                <option value="Seguridad">Seguridad</option>
                                                                <option value="Higiene">Higiene</option>
                                                                <option value="Ergonomia">Ergonomia</option>
                                                                <option value="Psicosociologia">Psicosociologia</option>
                                                                <option value="Higiene">Higiene</option>
                                                            </select>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="col-md-2">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label for="">Vencimiento</label>
                                                                <input type="date" name="fecha_ta" class="form-control" required>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                                            <label for="">Estado</label>
                                                            <select class="form-select form-select-sm" name="estado_ta" aria-label=".form-select-sm example">
                                                                <option value="<?php echo $estado_ta ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $estado_ta ?></option>
                                                                <option value>Seleccione</option>
                                                                <option value="En curso">En curso</option>
                                                                <option value="Completado">Completado</option>
                                                                <option value="Parcialmente hecho">Parcialmente hecho</option>
                                                                <option value="Pospuesto">Pospuesto</option>
                                                                <option value="Cancelado">Cancelado</option>

                                                            </select>

                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                                            <label for="">Accion Preventiva </label>
                                                            <select class="form-select form-select-sm" name="accionprl_ta" id="" class="form-control">
                                                                <?php
                                                                foreach ($accionprl_datos as $accionprl_dato) {
                                                                    $accionprl_tabla = $accionprl_dato['codigo_acc'];
                                                                    $id_accion = $accionprl_dato['id_accion']; ?>
                                                                    <option value="<?php echo $id_accion; ?>" <?php if ($accionprl_tabla == $accionprl_ta) { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>>
                                                                        <?php echo  $accionprl_tabla; ?>
                                                                    </option>
                                                                <?php
                                                                }
                                                                ?>
                                                            </select>
                                                        </div>


                                                        <div class="row">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label for="">Detalles de tarea</label>
                                                                <textarea class="form-control" name="detalles_ta" rows="10"></textarea>
                                                            </div>

                                                        </div>




                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-footer">

                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="bi bi-floppy"></i> Guardar</button>

                                                    </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                    <!--fin modal-->






                            </td> ```
````

y ahora el controlador al que recojo los datos pasados por el modal y basicamente los inserto en la tabla que le corresponde:

```
include('../../../app/config.php');

$id_tarea = $_POST['id_tarea'];
$id_proyecto = $_POST['id_proyecto'];
$nombre_ta = $_POST['nombre_ta'];
$fecha_ta = $_POST['fecha_ta'];
$fechareal_ta = $_POST['fechareal_ta'];
$centro_ta = $_POST['centro_ta'];
$responsable_ta = $_POST['responsable_ta'];
$prioridad_ta = $_POST['prioridad_ta'];
$estado_ta = $_POST['estado_ta'];
$programada_ta = $_POST['programada_ta'];
$detalles_ta = $_POST['detalles_ta'];
$categoria_ta = $_POST['categoria_ta'];
$accionprl_ta = $_POST['accionprl_ta'];


$sentencia = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO ag_tareas (id_tarea, id_proyecto, nombre_ta, fecha_ta, centro_ta, responsable_ta, prioridad_ta, estado_ta, programada_ta, detalles_ta, categoria_ta, accionprl_ta) 
VALUES(NULL, :id_proyecto, :nombre_ta, :fecha_ta, :centro_ta, :responsable_ta, :prioridad_ta, :estado_ta, :programada_ta, :detalles_ta, :categoria_ta, :accionprl_ta)");

$sentencia->bindParam('id_tarea', $id_tarea);  
$sentencia->bindParam('id_proyecto', $id_proyecto);    
$sentencia->bindParam('nombre_ta', $nombre_ta);    
$sentencia->bindParam('fecha_ta', $fecha_ta);
$sentencia->bindParam('fechareal_ta', $fechareal_ta);
$sentencia->bindParam('centro_ta', $centro_ta);
$sentencia->bindParam('responsable_ta', $responsable_ta);
$sentencia->bindParam('prioridad_ta', $prioridad_ta);    
$sentencia->bindParam('estado_ta', $estado_ta);
$sentencia->bindParam('programada_ta', $programada_ta);
$sentencia->bindParam('detalles_ta', $detalles_ta);
$sentencia->bindParam('categoria_ta', $categoria_ta);
$sentencia->bindParam('accionprl_ta', $accionprl_ta);

if ($sentencia->execute()) {
session_start();
$_SESSION['mensaje'] = "Tarea editada correctamente";
$_SESSION['icono'] = 'success';
header("Location: " . $URL . "/admin/actividad/show.php?id_proyecto=$id_proyecto");
} else {
session_start();
$_SESSION['mensaje'] = "Tarea NO editada";
$_SESSION['icono'] = 'warning';
header("Location: " . $URL . "/admin/actividad/show.php?id_proyecto=$id_proyecto");
}
```